# Enabling incremental backups in C* using nodetool

Tags: cassandra

Nodetool supports following command to enable incremental backups - 
nodetool enablebackup
However, in cassandra.yaml file, it says that we need to set the setting to true and restart the node.
When I run nodetool enablebackup, it does not update the setting in cassandra.yaml file. So how do we check whether running nodetool enablebackup command actually enabled incremental backups?

What is the best practice to enable incremental backups?

Answer (score 0):

By using the nodetool utility you don't actually change the cassandra.yaml file, nodetool can be used for dynamic changes.

There is no option currently in nodetool that will indicate whether incremental backup was turned on or off.

Whenever cassandra starts up it will read the cassandra.yaml file and use that as the final configuration.

As can be seen using nodetool can make it difficult to track certain things, but currently there is no way to detect if the command really had the desired effect other than observing the consequences of the command.

Answer (score 0):

`./nodetool statusbackup` can be used to check the the status of it.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Dt73.png)